# YTPlayer background video does not play automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

I have integrated the plugin https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer, following the documentation examples and I have not been able to start the video automatically, the user must click to play it.

There is a way that this click can be simulated, or some solution for the video to start loading without any user action.

**Full code of the example:** https://jsfiddle.net/py7bkox3/

**HTML**

```
<div id="video"></div>
<div id="ctn">
  <h1>TITLE EXAMPLE</h1>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
// When the document is ready
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Initialize YouTube player
  $("#video").YTPlayer({
    // URL of the YouTube video
    videoURL:'https://youtu.be/BsekcY04xvQ',
    // If you want it as background of your website
    // or of an element e.g #elementId
    containment: "#ctn",
    autoplay: true,
    controls: 0,
    mute: true,
    startAt: 0,
    opacity: 1,
    // Hide YouTube Controls
    showControls: false,
    onReady: function(){
    },
    onError: function(err){
      console.log("An error ocurred", err);
    }
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#ctn {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 250px 0 !important;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many browsers block autoplay with, or without, sound. This is likely an issue with your browser, and not the code itself.

[image: Firefox permissions screen]
This is a screenshot of my autoplay settings in Firefox. I'd check your browser settings, and see if its blocking autoplay.